# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una lista como parametro de una web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

tengo la siguiente API:

```
[Route("api/Expedientes/{idDocs}/{idFiles}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostExpediente([FromUri] List<int> idDocs, [FromUri] List<int> idFiles, [FromBody]ExpedientePOCO expedientePOCO)
    {
    }
```

y así es como la consumo:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54585/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Expedientes/"+idDocs+"/"+idFiles, expediente).Result;
```

donde idDocs y idFiles son listas de enteros (List)

sin embargo, no puedo accesar a ella! Asumo que no paso correctamente los parametros! O si hay alguna manera de mandar los 3 parametros fromBody ni cosa mejor jejeje

Ayuda y gracias!

Comment: Tal vez esto te pueda servir [HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value)

Comment: hace + idDocs, si son de tipo list, solo esta concatenando el tostring() de la clase, que no es la lista que contiene, si no el nombre del objeto...

Answer (score 1):

cuando envíes los parámetros desde la `Uri`, ésta debe ser como este formato

```
/MiApi?idDocs=value1&idDocs=value2&idDocs=3&idFiles=1&idFiles=2&idFiles=3 ....
```